# Force the ngRepeat directive instantiates a template each time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following directive :

```
.directive("testDir",function(){
            var templateCreation = 0;
            return {
                template : function(){
                    return "<div id='myTestDirId-'"+(++templateCreation)+">Test dir : "+templateCreation+"</div>";
                },
                scope : {},
                link: function (scope){}
            }
        })
```

My goal is to have an unique id each time the directive is created. Thats not working if the directive is included into a ng-repeat. For exemple :

```
<test-dir></test-dir>
<test-dir></test-dir>
<div ng-repeat="r in [1,2,3]">
   <test-dir></test-dir>
</div>
```

will result in

```
Test dir : 1
Test dir : 2
Test dir : 3 -> id attribute = myTestDirId-3
Test dir : 3 -> id attribute = myTestDirId-3
Test dir : 3 -> id attribute = myTestDirId-3
```

But I would like to have this :

```
Test dir : 1
Test dir : 2
Test dir : 3 -> id attribute = myTestDirId-3
Test dir : 4 -> id attribute = myTestDirId-4
Test dir : 5 -> id attribute = myTestDirId-5
```

Any idea how to force the ng-repeat to build the directive again?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service to manage the incrementing of your id.

Simple example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive("testDir", function(idService) {
    return {
      template: function() {
        return "<div class='myTestDir'>Test dir : {{id}}</div>";
      },
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.id = idService.getId()
      }
    }
  }).service('idService', function() {
    this.id = 0
    this.getId = () =>  ++this.id;   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <test-dir></test-dir>
  <test-dir></test-dir>
  <div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]">
    <test-dir></test-dir>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The service is not a solution. I need to have a unique id during the template initialization. The important part is the id attribute : <div id='UNIQUE_ID'>blabla</div>. And I can't not set this attribute during the link in my case.